# Is there a general binary intermediate representation for OpenCL kernel programming?

Tags: opencl, llvm, llvm-ir

as I understood, the OpenCL uses a modified C language (by adding some keywords like __global) as the general purpose for defining kernel function. And now I am doing a front-end inside F# language, which has a code quotation feature that can do meta programming (you can think it as some kind of reflection tech). So I would like to know if there is a general binary intermediate representation for the kernel instead of C source file.

I know that CUDA supports LLVM IR for the binary intermediate representation, so we can create kernel programmatically, and I want to do the same thing with OpenCL. But the document says that the binary format is not specified, each implementation can use their own binary format. So is there any general purpose IR which can be generated by program and can also run with NVIDIA, AMD, Intel implementation of OpenCL?

Thansk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not yet. Khronos is working on [SPIR](http://codedivine.org/2012/10/07/opencl-spir/) (the spec is still provisional), which would hopefully become this. As far as I can tell, none of the major implementations support it yet. Unless you want to bet your project on its success and possibly delay your project for a year or two, you should probably start with generating code in the C dialect.